# ASP.NET Base64String Image to SVG

Tags: asp.net

I am generating a QR Code and I am trying to get it as a SVG so I can display it in an email.

My part of the code I am having issues with is this:

```
using (Bitmap bitMap = qrCode.GetGraphic(20))
{
    using (MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream())
    {
        bitMap.Save(ms, System.Drawing.Imaging.ImageFormat.Png);
        byte[] byteImage = ms.ToArray();
        imgBarCode.ImageUrl = "data:image/png;base64," + Convert.ToBase64String(byteImage);
    }
}
```

I am trying to convert imgBarCode.ImageUrl to SVG, but I have no idea how to do this, any help would be appreciated.

Comment: I doubt it is possible without a specialized plugin/library since `SVG` is a vector image. But why not just display the `png` in the email?

Comment: I am okay with png.